# Turning mvnpdf into symbolic function so that I can take the gradient

Tags: matlab

I need to compute the gradient of the mvnpdf function in Matlab.
The first step is to create a symbolic function from mvnpdf.
This is my code:

```
syms a b c d e;
test = symfun(mvnpdf([a b], [c d], [e 0; 0 e]), [a b c d e]);
```

and the error I get is:

```
Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Error in cholcov (line 41)
tol = 10*eps(max(abs(diag(Sigma))));

Error in mvnpdf (line 127)
        [R,err] = cholcov(Sigma,0);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want a numerical gradient or a symbolic one? Either is possible, but in no case do you need the symbolic toolbox as long as you know how to differentiate an exponential function.

Comment: I need the symbolic one.